# Asp.Net 4.0 ListView: Does not display LinkButton when value of another column is changed

Tags: asp.net, listview

Let's say my ListView has a column named Type. This column has either one of these two values: 0 or 1. In case Type = 0, I want to show a LinkButton with text "Delete" so that whenever user clicks Delete, Type is change to 1. In case Type = 1, I don't want to show LinkButton "Delete". My codes look like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="listview" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
   ...
   <ItemTemplate>
      ...
      <td><asp:Label ID="labelTypeValue" runat="server"><%#Eval("Type")%></asp:Label></td>
      <td><asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton></td>
      ...
   </ItemTemplate>
   ...
</asp:ListView>
```

With these codes, the LinkButton is always shown regarding of the value of Type. How can I do as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonDelete" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Type").ToString() == "0"%>' CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton></td>
```